venv\Scripts\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
I'm working with Python 3.11.9 and Django 4.2.4 for my project. However, I've encountered an issue where the FastCGI process exits unexpectedly with the following error message:

kttProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly.

Despite attempting various troubleshooting steps, including checking permissions and seeking solutions from online resources, I haven't been able to resolve this error.
Could someone please provide insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Could you include in the question the Visual C++ redistributable that you have installed and whether its path is included. You might need to download both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, You could also check XDebug versions.
